# Conditional type of second function argument

Tags: typescript, literals, typescript-generics

I have following function:

```
function doSomething(param1: string, param2: string) {
  return param1 + param2;
}
```

also I have json based type with structure looking similar to this:

```
a1: {
  b1: 'something1',
  b2: 'something2',
  b3: 'something3'
},
a2: {
  c1: 'something4',
  c2: 'something5'
}

...etc
```

I want nth argument of mentioned function to be literal of nth deep elements, so if first argument is `'a1'`, second should be `'b1' | 'b2' | 'b3'`, and if first argument is `'a2'`, second should be `'c1' | 'c2'`.

For first argument I've made simple `keyof typeof data` type, which is working great:

```
// data is imported json
type FirstArg = keyof typeof data;
```

For second I was trying generic type like this, but without success:

```
type SecondArg<T extends FirstArg> = keyof typeof data[T];
```

Any chance to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it for any number of arguments, you can define overloads for up to a specific depth:

```
const data = {
    a1: {
        b1: 'something1',
        b2: 'something2',
        b3: 'something3'
    },
    a2: {
        c1: 'something4',
        c2: 'something5'
    }
}
type DataType = typeof data;
function doSomething<K extends keyof DataType, K2 extends keyof DataType[K]>(p1: K, p2: K2, p3: keyof DataType[K][K2]): string
function doSomething<K extends keyof DataType>(p1: K, p2: keyof DataType[K]): string
function doSomething(p1: keyof DataType): string
function doSomething(...keys: PropertyKey[]) {
    return keys.join('.');
}

doSomething("a1", "b1")
doSomething("a1", "c2") // err
```

Comment: Thanks, that's sufficient solution for my problem.