# Typescript typing function with 2 params one is key in other

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given:

```
const I18 = { EN: { M1: { A: 'Hi' } } };


(page: Keys, label:string ) => () => string | string
```

Usage

```js
const current = 'EN';
const T = (param1, param2) => I18[current][param1][param2];

console.log( T('M1','A') ) //  return 'hi';
```

How can I write type def for this? I tried:

```
type Opts = keyof typeof I18;
type Keys = keyof typeof I18.EN;
```

So I can easy type param1, and current variable; but how to provide checking for param2?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAkgRgBwwLwwN4wKIDkBcmMAsgoVgIKEBEAEgJbUwC+LLA3AFCiSzACuAJ0EBTMLHTU81LpygBPAA4j4yAMJC0MBcpAAzVUgDaOkfpgDhYqAF0uPaDAAqWgDwBpBDBEAPKGIATCBgAaxF5c0QkDUEAPgAKRQBDQSSAWzIYTwAaGGTUtIAmQjCIgyiYo08bAEo0WM4YQyNLUXEbI3z0hA6uortObnAIEAAbEQA6UZAAc3jneIByUkXsxYpFurqAem2m0SghMBhFgAt6RfYYTiA) meet your needs?  I'm having a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: I asked similar question few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832955/conditional-type-of-second-function-argument